# Scaling CSS border-radius

Tags: html, css

Say I have the following CSS circle but want to change the width & height to 320px each.  How would I properly scale `-moz-border-radius`, `-webkit-border-radius`, `border-radius` ?

Seems like if I just make all the border-radii 320px the circle shape is maintained but not sure if this is the correct method.

```
#circle {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    -moz-border-radius: 50px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
}
```

Comment: set the border-radius to 50%

Answer (score 3):

If you have a **square** of any width/height, simply set `border-radius: 50%;` This should then give a circle no matter how the element is scaled.

```css
#circle1 {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #E74C3C;
}

#circle2 {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #F1C40F;
  position: absolute;
  left: 125px;
}

#circle3 {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #2ECC71;
  position: absolute;
  left: 225px;
}
```

```html
<div id="circle1" />
<div id="circle2" />
<div id="circle3" />
```